# Get all items in ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-flex-layout

I have a grid component. I want it to take in a variable amount of items and display them in a row. Something like this:

`grid.component.html`

```
<ng-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="12px"> 
    for ng-item-in-component -> item:
        <item fxFlex="1"></item>
</ng-content>
```

How can I do this without knowing what the item passed in will be?

An example usage would be:

```
<app-grid>
    <app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>
</app-grid>
```

This would result in:

```
<app-grid fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="12px">
    <app-hero-detail fxFlex="1"></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail fxFlex="1"></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail fxFlex="1"></app-hero-detail>
    <app-hero-detail fxFlex="1"></app-hero-detail>
</app-grid>
```

Comment: Unable to understand! and what is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate components via the items variable?

Comment: Explain it better. I can't understand it as well

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I updated the example, does that help?

Comment: @nitin9nair I want to iterate whatever content is inside of the ng-content tag. If 100 divs were passed in, then I would want to iterate them

Comment: @user82395214 How you would come to know about there are 100 items? and which items? Source of those items? example of the items?

Comment: Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckb1xb). Is this correct what I am understanding

Comment: @nitin9nair Thank you for the resource. I updated it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckb1xb). Now inside of grid on the `ng-content` tag there would be `fxLayout="row"` (im not sure how to include FlexLayout here). Then, I'm asking how I can iterate through the hello tags without knowing they are hello tags (could be any item) and adding the `fxFlex="1"` property to them

Comment: I am unable to see your changes in that link. You have to fork it and save your changes and add that link here.

Comment: @nitin9nair [New link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzjj9y)

Comment: Check this [new stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phodm6?file=src/app/app.component.html) based on your question

Comment: @nitin9nair Right so for [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srsbya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid.component.ts) these content blocks should be in a flex grid.